# Iterating through a generic list property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a class

```
public class SearchViewModel<T> where T:class
    {
        public string LastSortColumn { get; set; }
        public string LastSortDirection { get; set; }
        public List<T> SearchItems;
        public SearchViewModel(List<T> SearchItems)
        {
            this.SearchItems = SearchItems;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way that I can iterate through the property SearchItems with a foreach loop or something? PS: SearchViewModel is also my model

Comment: Sure, `foreach(var element in SearchItems)` { ... }`. Honestly: why not google "how to iterate a list in c#"?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yea but SearchViewModel is also my model

Comment: @john Why does that prevent you from using Google?

Comment: @john Considering the "answer" to your question is something that you'd have seen hundreds of thousands of times in the search results if you had actually searched for your question, yes, it's crystal clear that you didn't search before you came here.  You seem to be under the false impression that everyone on this site is your slave, and we exist purely to serve you.  That is simply false.  We don't exist just so you don't have to bother using Google when you have a question.

Comment: @Servy strange thing is that the one who helped me got a downvote... so poor

Comment: It's damn funny to see that you know how to write a generic data class, properties, generic lists and a parameterized constructor, but doesn't know how to loop through a list. `foreach(var item in List) { }`. This is all you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use var here, the compiler than will decide in the foreach loop from which type the SearchItem in the list is. In this example var is of type string/

```
     SearchViewModel<string> vs = new SearchViewModel<string>(new List<string> { "1","2","3"});

     foreach (var item in vs.SearchItems)
     {
        // logic, item in this case is string 
     }
```